# Previous view not disappearing after clicking next button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make my own multi-step form with Bootstrap and jQuery. However, when clicking the "Next" button, the previous pane does not get replaced by the next/new pane, instead, the new pane appears just under the previous pane.

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;

 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

 //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

 //show the next fieldset
 next_fs.show();
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
   scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
   left = (now * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
   next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
  },
  duration: 800,
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  },
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;

 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

 //de-activate current step on progressbar
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

 //show the previous fieldset
 previous_fs.show();
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
   scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
   left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'left': left});
   previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
  },
  duration: 800,
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  },
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
})
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    background: #6441A5; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #6441A5, #2a0845); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
    background: transparent;
}

/*form styles*/
#msform {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: relative;
}

/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}

/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#msform input:focus, #msform textarea:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #ee0979;
    outline-width: 0;
    transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
}

/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #ee0979;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #ee0979;
}

#msform .action-button-previous {
    width: 100px;
    background: #C5C5F1;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button-previous:hover, #msform .action-button-previous:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #C5C5F1;
}

/*headings*/
.fs-title {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
}

#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 26px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}

/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none;
}

/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before, #progressbar li.active:after {
    background: #ee0979;
    color: white;
}


/* Not relevant to this form */
.dme_link {
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.dme_link a {
    background: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ee0979;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.dme_link a:hover, .dme_link a:focus {
    background: #C5C5F1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Sell</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sellForm.css">
  </head>
  <!-- MultiStep Form -->

  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <form id="msform">
          <!-- progressbar -->
          <ul id="progressbar">
            <li class="active"></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
          <!-- fieldsets -->
          <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Step 1</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Tell us more about your device.</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="brand">Brand</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="brand" required>
                <option>Apple</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="model">Model</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="model" required>
                <option>iPhone X</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="warranty">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="warranty">
                Device is still under manufacturer warranty.
              </label>
              <small id="warrantyInfo" class="form-text text-muted">We pay more for devices that are still under manufacturer warranty.</small>
            </div>
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Step 2</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Now we need to know more about your device's condition.</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="screen">How is your device's <b>screen</b>?</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="screen" required>
                <option>Flawless, no scratches!</option>
                <option>1-2 light scratches</option>
                <option>3 or more scratches</option>
                <option>Cracked or damaged</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="body">How is your device's <b>body</b>?</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="body" required>
                <option>Flawless, no scratches or bends!</option>
                <option>1-2 light scratches</option>
                <option>3 or more scratches</option>
                <option>Bent or severely damaged</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="power">Is your device able to <b>power on</b>?</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="power" required>
                <option>Yes</option>
                <option>No</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="charge">Is your device able to <b>charge</b>?</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="charge" required>
                <option>Yes</option>
                <option>No</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="calls">Is your device able to <b>make calls</b>?</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="calls">
                <option>Yes</option>
                <option>No</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Step 3</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Here's what we can offer for your device.</h3>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.MultiStep Form -->
    <script src="sellForm.js"></script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b65gepu1/

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: There is a console error when I click Next button:
(index):255 Uncaught TypeError: current_fs.animate is not a function

Comment: @Arsi It might be because I'm using the slim build of jQuery. Will try it out with the full build, thanks!

Comment: @Arsi added the full version of jQuery, but still unable to fix the problem :-/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/piyush05/7hn9b3ox/2/
Is this correctly working? Please check

Comment: @Piyush yes it is! May I know what you changed? Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok then, let me add in answer maybe others may get help.

Comment: @Piyush sure, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203506/discussion-between-piyush-and-narypigeon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to two reasons:

1. The slim version of jQuery has no animate function.
2. You missed to include custom easing plugin.

So to correct the imports, you need to add:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

and use minified version instead of slim version of jQuery.

Hope it helps.